# SQL Alchemy TypeError: where() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Simple Python SQLAlchemy `where()`, but driving me crazy with this error. Can't figure it out.

```
In [1]: import sqlalchemy as sa
   ...: import pandas as pd
   ...: 
   ...: import etl_utils as eu

In [2]: engine = eu.set_db('s','username',input('enter password:\t'),
   ...:                    sql_database_name='DBNAME')

In [3]: meta = sa.MetaData(engine)
   ...: meta.reflect()
```

... redacted ...

```
In [6]: tbl
Out[6]: Table('factSecurityPrices', MetaData(bind=Engine(mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=redacted)), Column('SecurityID_FK', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('dimSecurities.SecurityID_PK'), table=<factSecurityPrices>), Column('ImportInfoID_FK', INTEGER(), ForeignKey('dimImportInfo.ImportInfoID_PK'), table=<factSecurityPrices>), Column('PriceDate', DATETIME(), table=<factSecurityPrices>), Column('SecurityPrice', DECIMAL(precision=22, scale=4), table=<factSecurityPrices>), schema=None)
In [7]: tbl.update().where(ImportInfoID_FK=398).values(SecurityPrice=8.5)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-dfa9428585e6>", line 1, in <module>
    tbl.update().where(ImportInfoID_FK=398).values(SecurityPrice=8.5)

TypeError: where() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ImportInfoID_FK'
```

Why on earth can't I pass a `kwarg` to `where()`?? All the examples and documentation online show that you could!

**Edit:**
Tried using the suggestions in the comments, didn't work:

```
In [8]: tbl.update().where(tbl.ImportInfoID_FK=398).values(SecurityPrice=8.5)
  File "<ipython-input-8-53fb97b0906a>", line 1
    tbl.update().where(tbl.ImportInfoID_FK=398).values(SecurityPrice=8.5)
                      ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression


In [9]: tbl.update().where(tbl.c.ImportInfoID_FK=398).values(SecurityPrice=8.5)
  File "<ipython-input-9-c1ceb5a2591f>", line 1
    tbl.update().where(tbl.c.ImportInfoID_FK=398).values(SecurityPrice=8.5)
                      ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Comment: Thanks guys, but not working, says keyword can't be expression, I edited the question

Comment: .values() use "named arguments" but where() method use tbl.c.column_name

Comment: Using a single `=` turns your where clause into an expression, which is illegal. use `==` instead.

Comment: @Bart Van Loon That's the answer!! Thanks!

Comment: no problem. I already gave it as a real answer too :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `.where(tbl.c.ImportInfoID_FK==398)`. See [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html?highlight=whereclause#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.update.params.whereclause) for more explanation.